# How to set expiry date in excel file

Tags: c#

How to set expiry date in excel file. I have tried below code but not column not working properly.
Kindly help on fix this issue . Thanks in advance.

```
 public static void AddPermission()
        {
            Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Workbook ExcelWorkBook = null;
            ExcelApp.Visible = true;
            ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Workspace\OneModernize\April\Mywork\excelAccesssNet\TFSStatus.xlsx"); /// add excel path
            ExcelWorkBook.Activate();
            ExcelWorkBook.Permission.Enabled = true;
            DateTime dtExpireDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            /// Add user mail xxx@cognizant.com
            ExcelWorkBook.Permission.Add("xxx@cognizant.com", MsoPermission.msoPermissionFullControl, ExpirationDate: dtExpireDate);
            ExcelWorkBook.Close();
            ExcelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
        

        }
```